# xdmp:node-delete funny behavior

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

When I used [xdmp:node-delete](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:node-delete) on an not existing node, it works on the query console but in CPF it throws `XDMP-ARGTYPE: (err:XPTY0004) xdmp:node-delete(()) -- arg1 is not of type node()`

Following is what I do in my query console

```
let $_ := xdmp:node-delete(fn:doc($uri)/enevelope:document-enevelope/enevelope:extractedText)
```

The document does not have the node, but on query console it does not complain, but it does give an error when used in the CPF?

Comment: In the error message, your XPath looks to evaluate to an empty sequence. Make sure that that path is correct, including namespace bindings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often times when something works in `Query Console` but doesn't work when I'm running it in a module its a permissions problem.

As Justin said it, the error shows that you have an empty sequence. That could be happening because of the `xpath` like he said or it could also being happening because the user running the query cant see the document. I'd check to make sure the document is coming back. Debugging `CPF` is a pain, to check I'd just `xdmp:log` it.

You could also do an eval as that user in query console.

Comment: Also keep in mind, the element could be really missing. Or the code might get executed twice, and the second time round the element has already been removed. Maybe enable diagnostics, add `CPF` as trace event, and check ErrorLog for CPF flow..